# Firebase's Anonymous Auth generates a new UserID in Unity Editor

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

In older API's, there was a method:

`FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorAuthUserId(SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier);`

In the new API, there's no such method.

Each time I call `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()`, I get a new login entry, with a new, randomly generated ID.

Is this only in the editor? If so, how to bypass that?

Comment: Are you signing out and then calling signInAnonymously? if so that should return a new user id. but if you don't sign out, the user should persist.

Comment: No, the framework is broken, as stated on their github issues.

Comment: If this is a known issue in their github repo, you should add the link to it. It could be helpful to others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It actually makes sense that every time the function is called, it generates a new ID; even though it has a limitation which stops abuse by limiting the creation of accounts from the [same IP for some time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth). I would recommend that you separate this functionality like for example, only when the app is open and then save an external property to cache to know that an anonymous ID has been asigned to that user.

Besides that, I would encourage to suggest the correctly sign in after the user ends doing what he is available in the anonymous functionality and then